# jquery onclick id & values of html elements

Tags: php, jquery

I have a table of records where each row has got a save button.
would someone please help me to get the id of the button and values of two inputs on button click

```
<input class="price" name="price" id="price_<?= $value['i_id'] ?>" value="<?= &cost ?>" />                         
<input type="hidden" id="<?= $value['i_id'] ?>_suffix" value="<?= $value['suffix'] ?>" /> 
<button type="button" class="sp-save btn btn-xs btn-primary btn-bell m-l-xs" id="save_<?= $value['i_id'] ?>">SAVE</button>
```

jquery

```
 save_id = $(this).attr(\'id\'); 
          id = save_id.replace( /save_/, \' \' ); //this is id of the button
price = $(\'#\'+\'price_\'+id).val(); // values comes undefined         

s_id = $(\'#\'+id+\'_suffix\').val();  //values comes undefined
```

Comment: Simpler to just use classes and look for each class within the specific row

Comment: just use a data attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good idea to [use a data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to set and retrieve `id` on button click. Below, I added a data attribute to the button and used jQuery's [data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) to get the `id` on click.

```
<input class="price" name="price" id="price_<?= $value['i_id'] ?>" value="<?= &cost ?>" />                         
<input type="hidden" id="<?= $value['i_id'] ?>_suffix" value="<?= $value['suffix'] ?>" /> 
<button type="button" class="sp-save btn btn-xs btn-primary btn-bell m-l-xs" id="save_<?= $value['i_id'] ?>" data-id="<?= $value['i_id'] ?>">SAVE</button>
```

jQuery:

```
id = $(this).data('id');       
price = $('#'+'price_'+id).val();         
s_id = $('#'+id+'_suffix').val();
```

Comment: A little explanation might be helpful. What was the problem and how does your code solve it?

Comment: It's good idea to use data attribute  to set id and retrieve id on button click.
So In above code I have added data attribute to button.

In jQuery:

I have used this data attribute to get id on click